# coinbase-node: Scopes don't match current API version

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, coinbase-api

Im building a website were users authenticate through coinbase and then let the website act on behalf of the user by connection with Auth2. The problem occurs when I'm connecting with Auth2.
https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node

```
var client = new Client({'accessToken': accessToken, 'refreshToken':refreshToken});
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
InvalidScope: Scopes don't match current API version.
at handleHttpError (/home/rasmus/Documents/bitlounge/node_modules/coinbase/lib/errorHandler.js:46:15)
at Request.onGet [as _callback] (/home/rasmus/Documents/bitlounge/node_modules/coinbase/lib/ClientBase.js:155:10)
at Request.self.callback (/home/rasmus/Documents/bitlounge/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/home/rasmus/Documents/bitlounge/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/rasmus/Documents/bitlounge/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
```

I've tried using the `'wallets:accounts:read'` scope but have had no success.

```
var client = new Client({'accessToken': user.accessToken, 'refreshToken': user.refreshToken, "scope": ["wallet:accounts:read"]});
```

Comment: I faced this same error message. Be sure you don't have any API v1 scope selected. It seems that libraries won't work if you select scopes from both versions.

Comment: I'm using passport-coinbase to authenticate users with the scope `['user']`. I'm guessing that is API v1, what should I change it too?

Comment: I was working with coinbase-python. I don't know passport-coinbase. But I guess this applies as well. From what I understood, the current versions of the libraries work with both v1 and v2, just not at the same time. You have to select either v1 or v2. v2 has all the scopes that v1 has and more. So I suggest going to API settings and uncheck all v1 scopes, check the correct ones on v2 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase API doesn't support multi-version access for one key, you should disable v1 API for your key and keep only v2. If you also need v1 API, you can create separate API key and enable only v1 API.